# How to stick footer to bottom? With a little twist

Tags: css, footer, sticky-footer

So basicly i want to stick footer on the bottom of my page

But the content of my page is dynamic, so in some cases the content is long, in some cases it is short

I've searched through google and found many results, but when i try it, they work when the content is short, but if the content is long it will stick on the bottom of the window (not page) and overlap the content

It's not matter if it uses javascript, but if you have the pure CSS ones it will be better

Comment: This isn't working? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page?rq=1

Comment: Can you post , your trail code what you have used . we can help you

Comment: @grayb: I've tried, but it doesn"t work. I can' t try it again now,because I'm using phone

Comment: @aravind: the "overlap" ones uses position:absolute, I can't post complete code because I'm using phone now

Comment: @gamehelp16 You have adjusted the height to be the same as your footer size? Made it so the wrapper class includes all the content apart from the footer class?

Comment: @grayb adjust the height of what? The "pusher"? I've tried but it fails. When I'm back to home I will try again

Comment: The height needs to be the same for the pusher and footer classes and also the negative margin of the wrapper class. If you have some example code, I will try to help you further

Comment: @grayb okay, I will try it again later

Comment: @GrayB thanks, now it works :D My problem is just on wrong implementation :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't use a fixed position so it won't always show up at the bottom of your viewport.

CSS from [here](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)

You can also see a discussion about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page?rq=1)

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -142px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 142px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}

/*

Sticky Footer by Ryan Fait
http://ryanfait.com/

*/
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#footer{
    position:fixed; 
    bottom:0;
    height:200px;
}

body
{
    min-height:100%;
    padding-bottom:200px; /* same as footer height */
}
```

Comment: I will try it  again later

Comment: i've tried it, but  i don't want the footer to stick at the bottom of the window, but stick to the bottom of the document

Comment: sorry I misunderstood. Can you clarify what you want? Perhaps you mean "When the content height + footer height is less than the window height how do I stick the footer to the bottom of the window?"

Comment: so i want the footer sticks to the bottom if the content's length is less then the window's height and if the length of the content is more than the window's height the footer will be under the content. By the way it's solved now

Answer (score 0):

I could find a css solution ( Not 100% )

```
#footer {
   position:fixed;
   left:0px;
   bottom:0px;
   height:30px;
   width:100%;
   background:#999;
}

/* IE 6 */
* html #footer {
   position:absolute;
   top:expression((0-(footer.offsetHeight)+(document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : document.body.clientHeight)+(ignoreMe = document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop))+'px');
}
```

at this link below 
[Fixed css footer](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fixed-footer/)

You can take also look into other SO postings

[Footer position bottom and center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587740/footer-position-bottom-and-center)

[how to make footer fixed in a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189238/how-to-make-a-footer-fixed-in-the-page-bottom)